# Call to undefined method in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a model there is no error in my case, but it give me error

> Message: Call to undefined method Auth_model::chech_user()

Here is my code

Controller

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $params = array(
            'iteration_count_log2' => '8',
            'portable_hashes' => TRUE
        );
        $this->load->library('hash', $params);
        $this->load->model('auth_model');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
            print_r($this->auth_model->chech_user($_POST));
            exit;
        }

        $this->load->view('auth/login');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }
```

Model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function check_user($params = array())
    {
        echo 'done';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your directory structure where your `model` is placed please.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo within the code you've provided, you're trying to call `chech_user()` not `check_user()` within the controller.

Comment: OHHH... @steadweb that was my mistake,

Comment: Is that the fix? or is that a mistake you've made within the post? :)

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
 print_r($this->auth_model->chech_user($_POST));
```

to

```
 print_r($this->auth_model->check_user($_POST));
```

Comment: I.e. change chec**h** to chec**k** .